# Deleting all rows with the same email in csv file

Tags: python

I'd like to ask, how to delete all rows with the same email in csv file? Idea is to pick random rows, and if that row picked and printed out, delete all rows with it's email from file. Now code deletes only rows that are picked and printed. But if there were more rows with the same email it wouldn't delete them. How to fix it?

Full code: https://pastebin.com/qzHm4NSA
Data structure: https://ibb.co/wWXfL6X

```
def generate():
    global winningRows
    filename = enterFile()

    noOfWinners = 5
    winningNumbers = []
    while len(winningNumbers) < noOfWinners:
        luckyNumber = random.randint(1, totalEntries)
        if luckyNumber not in winningNumbers:
            winningNumbers.append(luckyNumber)

    with open(filename, newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")
        allRows = [row for row in entriesDict]
        winningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) in winningNumbers]
        nonWinningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) not in winningNumbers]
        for row in winningRows:
            winnerName = row["Name"]
            winnerID = row["ID"]
            winnerEmail = row["Email"]
            print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")

    with open(filename, "w", newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(entriesCSV, fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

Comment: Why don't you remove those rows from `nonWinningRows` so that they don't end up in the file? Or make a new list `resultRows` which contains `nonWinningRows` initially and then some more rows are removed from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a list of emails of the picked winners and then use it to filter out rows of non winners. For that,
Just modify the code segment as follows and that will solve your problem:

```
def generate():
    global winningRows
    filename = enterFile()

    noOfWinners = 5
    winningNumbers = []
    nonWinningRows = []           
    winnerEmails = []                #change 1
    while len(winningNumbers) < noOfWinners:
        luckyNumber = random.randint(1, totalEntries)
        if luckyNumber not in winningNumbers:
            winningNumbers.append(luckyNumber)

    with open(filename, newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")
        allRows = [row for row in entriesDict]
        winningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) in winningNumbers]
        for row in winningRows:
            if row["Email"] not in winnerEmails:          #change 2
                winnerName = row["Name"]
                winnerID = row["ID"]
                winnerEmail = row["Email"]
                print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")
                winnerEmails.append(winnerEmail)            #change 3
        nonWinningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) not in winningNumbers and row["Email"] not in winnerEmails]       #change 4

    with open(filename, "w", newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(entriesCSV, fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But those edits prints same rows at first and then deletes... I need to delete all same email rows after only one is printed out...

Comment: Your description is confusing then, from what you are saying, it implies that you have duplicates in your winningRows, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Because there can be same email with different ID.

Comment: @PineappleBros I've updated the code segment inside for loop, this should solve your problem

Comment: There's one more problem... When luckyNumber is not found between indexes (#) it is not printed on the screen. E.g. noOfWinners = 5 and there are only 3-4 rows printed out in the console.

Comment: This is different than what you have asked in your question. However, you need to change the algorithm for selecting the winning numbers in this regard. First, enlist all the distinct row numbers from allRows, then select winningNumbers randomly from that list.

Comment: Actually it was working like this before.